# Read .py file variables in another python file using the filepath

Tags: python

Considering I have two files - `abc.py` and `xyz.py`

`abc.py` contains the following code -

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dt = {'m':1, 'n':4, 'o':9}
```

I want to read the file `abc.py` and use the python variables in `xyz.py` just like how we import using `from abc import li, dt`.

The path to `abc.py` (say, `path/to/abc.py`) will be provided and I want to import the contents and use it in `xyz.py` just like python variables.

The following code provides the content in a string format, while I can do some coding and get the job done but I want to generalize and look for a better approach to this. Also note, I find using `abc.json` a better option but due to some reasons I cannot use it for my purpose.

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
    s = f.read()
    print(s)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: how about using json? `{"li": [1, 2, 3, 4],
"dt": {'m':1, 'n':4, 'o':9}}`. I don't think it's best idea to use variables from another python file instead you can use json, xml,etc..

Comment: Is there a reason you are accessing .py files like this for variable content? Is JSON unusable or? Have you considered csv? Have a look at various types of config files that will allow passing of a variable to your python script. https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/

Comment: Yes, it might not be the best idea but there is a reason I have to use `.py` file specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do not use abc.py as it will clash with another builtin with that name.

What you can do is to add the folder into sys, and then import it.

renaming, for example, to abcfile.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, folder_path)
import abcfile

print(abcfile.li)
```

`>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]`